React app won't write to Firebase Realtime Database
My React app won't write to my Firebase Realtime Database. I am doing everything exactly as the Firebase tutorials say but nothing. No error messages in the console or requests in the network tab either.
Do I have to change some settings on the Firebase side?
Firebase Rules
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}

.env (Real values obviously replaced by dummy values. Please note the use of double quotes around the values.)
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY="xxxxxx-----xxxxxxx"
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN="abcdef.firebaseapp.com"
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL="https://abc-def-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/"
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID="abc-def"
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET="abc-def.appspot.com"
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID="0000000000000"
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID="0:000000000000000:web:yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID="G-XXXXXXXXXXX"

firebase.js file.
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAnalytics } from 'firebase/analytics';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getDatabase } from 'firebase/database';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getDatabase(app);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

export { app, auth, db, analytics };

doStuffFile.ts
import { db } from 'firebaseConfig/firebase';
import { ref, set } from 'firebase/database';

function setUserData({
    totalCardsSeen,
    totalCardsAnswered,
    totalCardsCorrect,
    totalScore,
    totalScoreDigits,
    currentUser,
}: ISetUserData): void {
    const reference = ref(db, `users/${12333}`);
    set(reference, {
        totalCardsSeen: 3,
        totalCardsAnswered: 3,
        totalCardsCorrect: 3,
        totalScore: 3,
        totalScoreDigits: 3,
    });
}


The code looks fine at first glance. So if there are no error messages, the problem is likely in something we can't see here. For example, how certain are you that the process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL value is being passed in correctly? Did you try it with a hard-coded value instead?

Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/1e6riua/react_app_wont_write_to_firebase_realtime_database/

@FrankvanPuffelen I tried both with hard-cocded and env variables yet neither work.
